# WPF, handle with error and warning message

Tags: c#, wpf

I need advance. I send HTTP GET request and parse HTML response, if HTML response(html string) consist  some substring, I want sent to client app,(WPF app) some error/warning message.

In my solution, if html string consist some substring I throw new exception, it is stupid, what solution is suitable for this problem?

code is here:

```
    private bool SendRp(string postData)
    {
        bool result = false;

        const string parameters = @"&lok=1&rpI=3";
        string htmlStringResult = HttpPostReq(
            new Uri(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}{1}{2}", PokecUrl.Rp, Account.SessionId, parameters)), postData);
        try
        {
            if (htmlStringResult.ToLower(new CultureInfo("sk-Sk")).Contains("is is empty"))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("ID is empty!");
            }
            if (htmlStringResult.ToLower(new CultureInfo("sk-Sk")).Contains("id does not exist"))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("ID does not exist.");
            }
            if (htmlStringResult.ToLower(new CultureInfo("sk-Sk")).Contains("blocked"))
            {
                throw new WebException("Your ID is blocked!");
            }
            if (!htmlStringResult.ToLower(new CultureInfo("sk-Sk")).Contains("message was send"))
            {
                Match match = Regex.Match(htmlStringResult, @"\bhs=\w{15}\b");

                if (match.Success)
                {
                    result = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Some problem");  
                }

            }
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw exception;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I understand the problem is with throwing exceptions. Why is this a problem?

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to store multiple errors/warnings because of parsing the HTML, use a collection of messages.**

You can define such a message collection like this:

```
public class MessageCollection : Collection<Message>
{
}

public class Message
{
    public Message(Severity severity, string message)
    {
        Severity = severity;
        Message = message;
    }

    public Severity Severity { get; private set; }
    public string Message { get; private set; }
}

public enum Severity
{
    Error,
    Warning,
    Info
}
```

You can use these classes like this:

```
var messages = new MessageCollection();

messages.Add(new Message(Severity.Warning, "This is a warning"));
messages.Add(new Message(Severity.Error, "This is an error"));
```

This way you can collect multiple messages from parsing the HTML. If you like, you can still throw an exception, but then with these messages:

```
public class MessageException : Exception
{
    public MessageException(MessageCollection messages)
        : base("One or more messages were collected")
    {
        Messages = messages;
    }

    public MessageCollection Messages { get; private set; }
}
```

And then throw this exception like this:

```
var messages = new MessageCollection();

messages.Add(new Message(Severity.Warning, "This is a warning"));
messages.Add(new Message(Severity.Error, "This is an error"));

if (messages.Count > 0)
    throw new MessageException(messages);
```